# Navigation Bar Higher like Safari App

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, uinavigationbar

I was wondering if there is a way to create a navigationBar like the one in this photo:
http://s2.postimage.org/ewem26czd/foto.jpg

and there is a way to customize its background?

Comment: try something. think something. If get confused in code, then you are most welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly easy to customize a UINavigationBar. Simply create a subclass of it, and in the XIB where you find the UINavigationController, use the inspector on the right to change the class of the navigation controller's navigation bar to your subclass.

Comment: As far as I know you can't, at least not in a clean way. I remember seeing a WWDC lecture about this a while ago. Make a simple XIB for the UINavigationController subclass if you need and do it there.